# noneType error in BeautifulSoup - I would like its value to be replaced with 0

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm checking sports stats, but quite often there's no red cards, and so it comes back as a `noneType` error and it's quite an important stat so I can't just skip it. I'd like to be able to print "Red Cards" as "0" if the team got no red cards.

```
import requests
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
row = soup.select_one('.statRow:has(*:contains("Red Cards"))')

home_value12 = row.select_one('.statText--homeValue').text
away_value12 = row.select_one('.statText--awayValue').text
```

I had figured on using an if statement, but I can't seem to get it right - it either ignores the if statement or throws an error. I know there's ways to skip `noneType` errors, but I'd sooner not skip it, but count it as zero.

Thanks for your help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
import requests
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
row = soup.select_one('.statRow:has(*:contains("Red Cards"))')

try:
    home_value12 = row.select_one('.statText--homeValue').text
    away_value12 = row.select_one('.statText--awayValue').text
except AttributeError:
    home_value12 = 0
    away_value12 = 0
```

### Or

```
if home_value12 is not None:
    print(home_value12)
else:
    print(0)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for these. The first example throws this error:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

The second example doesn't seem to skip the NoneType error and stops the cogs from turning sadly.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't thinking. It is late here. I fixed that by making the 0 a string "0".